# Do I need to create a separate account for the PeduliLindungi app and the vaksinln.dto.kemkes.go.id site?

Tags: covid-19, indonesia

For entry to indonesia I think I need the following in regard to the COVID-19 measures

- register my vaccination through this website: https://vaksinln.dto.kemkes.go.id/
- download the PeduliLindungi app to show a specific indonesian approval (qr code) when arriving / entering venues

I assumed it would be a connected system, but my login from the website does not work with the app. Are these supposed to be different accounts? I ask before trying as I can imagine having 2 accounts in one name wouldn't be prefered. My vaccination proof hasn't been validated as of yet, which could be the reason it doesn't work yet?

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are different accounts.

Source: I just been through this process myself.